# Unable to plot D3 curve with negative values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to plot a bezier curve with D3. My code works but the only problem is that as soon as I make the values negative, my curve goes off the frame.

```
var bezierLine = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d[0]; })
    .y(function(d) { return d[1]; })
    .curve(d3.curveBasis);

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 350)


svg.append('path')
    .attr("d", bezierLine([[0, 40], [25, 70], [50, 100], [100, 50], [150, 20], [200, 130], [300, 120]]))
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("stroke-width", 4)
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", function() {
            var len = this.getTotalLength();
            return function(t) { return (d3.interpolateString("0," + len, len + ",0"))(t) };
        })
```

The graph goes off the frame when replacing the values as `.attr("d", bezierLine([[0, -40], [25, -70], [50, -100], [100, -50], [150, -20], [200, -130], [300, -120]]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This...

```
[[0, -40], [25, -70], [50, -100], [100, -50], [150, -20], [200, -130], [300, -120]]
```

...is your data. With very rare exceptions, data values do not correspond to SVG coordinates. That's the case when you want to create a bar chart with values like *4 billion* or line charts with values like *-120*. For these situations, use a **scale**, which will map data values to SVG coordinates. In you case:

```
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-150, 0])
  .range([350, 0]);
```

Here is your code using a scale for the `y` position:

```js
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-150, 0])
  .range([350, 0]);

var bezierLine = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d[0];
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return scale(d[1]);
  })
  .curve(d3.curveBasis);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 350);

svg.append('path')
  .attr("d", bezierLine([
    [0, -40],
    [25, -70],
    [50, -100],
    [100, -50],
    [150, -20],
    [200, -130],
    [300, -120]
  ]))
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("stroke-width", 4)
  .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", function() {
    var len = this.getTotalLength();
    return function(t) {
      return (d3.interpolateString("0," + len, len + ",0"))(t)
    };
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Do the same for the `x` position.

Comment: The code works perfectly, but just wanted to know why did you select the values of `.domain` and `.range` as -150 and 350. And how can we manipulate with height and width to make the graph smaller? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those are the values of your SVG (`height = 350`) and your data (from `-130` to `0`). I wrote `-150` by mistake, it should be `-130`. Also, since you asked, you can find those domain values programmatically (e.g. `d3.extent(data)`).

Comment: Yeah makes sense, can I plot the same graph with `range` as 200 and `domain` as 130 and add `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"` in the svg. And I'm new to D3 but shouldn't the height and width as `auto` should also work?

Comment: Well, that has nothing to do with D3.